# Opencv2 cvtColor() does not work

Tags: qt, opencv

I am using OpenCV2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I can successfully run image read-display codes.
However I am not able to run codes with inbuilt functions eg. cvtColor()

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("img.jpg");

    if( image.data == NULL )
    {
        printf( "file cannot be loaded\n");
        return 1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("My");
    cv::imshow("My", image);

    cv::Mat result;
    cv::cvtColor(image, result, CV_BGR2Luv);

    cv::imwrite("outImg.jpg", result);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Qt-creator for my OpenCV
After compiling with --libs, --cflags I get following compiler error:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/swaroop/Work/ai-junkies/cuda/uc_davis/opencv2.x/OpenCV2Test'
g++ -g -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/opencv -I. -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:22:29: error: 'CV_BGR2Luv' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:22:39: error: 'cvtColor' was not declared in this scope
```

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`cvtColor` declared in `opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp`

keep in mind it's **#include** not #import

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

Comment: you are correct. I had to #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>.

Comment: Is there an easy way to know (without asking) which header files to include?

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, if you are testing things and not concerned with overdoing the includes, you can simply have one line:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

and it will include most opencv2 headers.